# Devise when login strip whitespaces around password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, whitespace, strip

I'd like to let devise strip leading and trailing whitespaces around the users password.
So I changed in devise.rb

```
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
```

to

```
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email, :password ]
```

as suggested by documentation.

I restarted the server, but only email is stripped.

Even if I remove :email from that config the email still is stripped, but the password isn't.

rails is 3.2.12, devise is 2.1.3

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in User model:

```
alias :orig_valid_password? :valid_password?
def valid_password?(password)
  orig_valid_password?(password.strip)
end
```

Comment: Working in 3.5.2, 

config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :password ] => has no effect and can be removed.